# Blazor server communications optimisation

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am working on a blazor server web application.

I have to display a table with a big number of rows and columns.

I want to optimize.

Is there a way to enable data compression on blazor's websockets ?

Is there a compression enabled by defaut in Developpment or Production environnement ?

Thanks

Comment: The best optimization is to **NOT** display more data than necessary. No human can read 1000 rows in a single screen, and every browser will slow to a crawl trying to render very long tables. In *all* web sites paging and/or scrolling virtualization is used to load and display only what's needed

Comment: Blazor already offers [component virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Especially in Blazor Server, this means that only the rows that need to be displayed will be sent to the browser. [Overscan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#overscan-count-1) will load a few more object than necessary to make scrolling smoother

Comment: Yes, i have already limit rows count, but i need to optimize more

Comment: That's not what I said. You can't display more than 10-20 rows at a time, so why load any more? That's why paging is used, to load only one page of data at a time. If loading just 20 items takes too long, the problem won't be solved with compression. Which, by the way, is something managed by the web server, not Blazor

Comment: In fact user is scrolling with his mouse and i have to do virtual scrolling

Comment: So what's the problem? If you only load a couple of items at a time, why are you looking for data compression?

Comment: Because it is still heavy. When user scrolls down/up etc. i see > 1Mo total traffic

Comment: Why? Why is it heavy? What are you sending? What does your code do? You can't expect people to guess what's wrong. If you want help you'll have to explain what's wrong, what your code does, what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this is going to be best answer for this but figured I would post it anyway. As other's have commented it would be best to utilize virtualization or pagination along with other app optimizations, but your question made me curious.

After a quick google search turns out asp.net has [response compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

The code used (Placed both as the very first things in their respective methods):

- In Setup/ConfigureServices:

  ```
       services.AddResponseCompression(o =>
       {
           o.EnableForHttps = true;
           o.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
           o.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
           o.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
               new[] { "image/svg+xml" });
       });
       services.Configure<BrotliCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
       {
           options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
       });
       services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
       {
           options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
       });
  ```
- In Setup/Configure:

  ```
      app.UseResponseCompression();
  ```

Default Blazor server app:

- Default: 2.2kB transferred.
- With changes: 1.5kB transferred.

Loading my own Blazor server app and testing it:

- Default: 5.4kB transferred
- With changes: 3.7kB transferred

Overall these changes appear to compress what is being transferred a bit more and the compression could most likely be even further optimized, but these changes **should not** be a substitute for optimizing your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I Agree with all of you about optimization and pagging. I have tried what you wrote but this compression does not apply to websocket communications (i have checked with a sniffer...)